# What is the best way to send notification user to user ionic 3 / firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

i am working on a project with ionic 3 and firebase. and i use firebase auth & database.

what i mean by user to user notification is like "x added you as a friend" or "a new post from x" etc.

so when i click the add button, app will send a notification to target uid's device. simple as always.

my question is what is the best and easiest way to do this in ionic & firebase for both ios and android ?

i researched that on the net but there are tons of different ways to do that depend on different platforms i couldnt find specific solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **FCM**. Add **FCM** in your project. Now to send notification from user to user/users you need the **FCM token/tokens** of the another user/users. Then just call this API.

```
let notifcationObj: any = {
    "notification": {
      "title": "YOUR_TITLE",
      "body" : "x added you as a friend :)",
      "sound": "default",
      "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    },
    "data": {
      "match": "created",
      "matchId": "value2",
      "image": "www/assets/img/logo-gray.png"
    },
    "to": TOKEN/TOKENS(Another user's FCM token or token array),
    "priority": "high",
    "restricted_package_name": ""
  };

  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=YOUR_FCM_KEY'
  });

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

  this.http.post(url, notifcationObj, options)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('notification data -> ', data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('notification error -> ', error);
    });
```

This is best and easiest way to send notification from users end. Let me know if any other help needed.